# Python remove odd numbers and print only even

Tags: python-2.7

```
user = int(raw_input("Type 5 numbers"))
even = []

def purify(odd):
    for n in odd:
        even.append(n)
        if n % 2 > 0:
            print n



print purify(user)
```

Hello I am a beginner and I would like to understand what is wrong with this code.
The User chose 5 numers and I want to print the even numbers only.
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems:

You can't apply `int` to an overall string, just to one integer at a time.

So if your numbers are space-separated, then you should split them into a list of strings. You can either convert them immediately after input, or wait and do it within your `purify` function.

Also, your `purify` function appends every value to the list `even` without testing it first.

Also, your test is backwards -- you are printing only odd numbers, not even.

Finally, you should `return` the value of `even` if you want to print it outside the function, instead of printing them as you loop.

I think this edited version should work.

```
user_raw = raw_input("Type some space-separated numbers")
user = user_raw.split()   # defaults to white space

def purify(odd):
    even = []
    for n in odd:
        if int(n) % 2 == 0:
            even.append(n)
    return even

print purify(user)
```

Comment: Thannk you very much , really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

raw_input returns a string and this cannot be converted to type int.

You can use this:

```
user = raw_input("Input 5 numbers separated by commas: ").split(",")
user = [int(i) for i in user]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def purify(x):
    new_lst = []
    for i in x:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_lst.append(i)
    return new_lst
```

for search even

Answer (score 0):

[`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) would be the simplest way to "filter" even numbers:

```
output = filter(lambda x:~x&1, input)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def purify(list_number):
    s=[]
    for number in list_number:
        if number%2==0:    
            s+=[number]
    return s
```